# Train tensorflow on two sets of images, one containing "the thing" and one that doesn't

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, image-recognition

This is my first attempt with AI image recognition. I have three sets of images, all containing a *render* of car with different "options" like different brakes, roof color, etc.

- First set is known to contain `option_1` (199 items)
- Second set is known to **not** contain `option_1` (648 items)
- Third set - I don't have any information about any option, but all the images were rendered by the same engine like the two other sets (1207 items)

All images are 640x480 pixels.

My end goal here is to train a model that based on the first two sets will be able to tell me which images in the unknown set contain `option_1`

I came up with this code, but I am missing the part where the model trains on both yes\no image sets

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

# Set the directories for the training and testing data
train_dir = "path/to/training/directory"
test_dir = "path/to/testing/directory"

# Define the image size and batch size
img_size = (640, 360)
batch_size = 32

# Create the training and testing data generators
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=test_dir,
    target_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Define the model architecture
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=test_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs=10
)

# Save the model
model.save('my_image_recognition_model.h5')
```